# Bootstrap modal dialog button click event triggering on modal open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an application and need to open a `modal`, have the user fill in some details and save them once they click the modal button i have designated. I have used `jQuery` `on` to bind a `click` event for the button. problem is the click event is triggered when the modal opens.

Relevant parts of modal:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">Save Event</a>
```

Where i bind the event:

```
$('#save-event').on(
'click',
function(evt)
{
    console.log('triggered');
}
);
```

The console shows 'triggered' when i open the dialog. I open the dialog through:

```
<a href="#add-event-modal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">{% trans "Event also occurs on" %}</a>
```

Its a Django app so the curly braces. Any ideas what i could be doing wrong or is there another way to execute some logic once the user clicks the relevant button?

Comment: Do you have any link or may be a fiddle with your code. It's hard to figure out the problem without that.

Comment: Ignore the answer I just gave, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Here's fiddle for the code, http://jsfiddle.net/czACy/1/ but i can't reproduce the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be having 2 elements with the same id in the html and you are getting the event triggered when you are clicking on the other element.

Comment: This solved it. I had two elements with the same id, save-event, one being the modal button. Renaming one of them solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your jQuery code:

```
evt.stopPropagation();
```

Sorry, should clarify, add this to the code triggering the modal opening.

**Edit:** since you don't have direct access to the modal code, try the following in your jQuery:

```
$('#add-event-modal').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: The modal is being triggered by <a href="#add-event-modal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">{% trans "Event also occurs on" %}</a>. The only JS relating to the modal is the click event above.

Comment: See edit for possible solution. There is some other JS firing to create the modal, HTML won't do that by itself. It's presumably built into your framework so you're not directly aware of it. This is certainly not a guaranteed fix, but I believe I ran into a similar problem a while back and resolved it in a similar fashion.